# LINQ expression to select based on visibility asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, logic

So I have a list with `post` objects that have a `visibility` enum property. I'm trying to get all posts that have `visibility == visibility.public` and `visibility == visibility.private && AuthorId == currentUserId`.

This doesn't seem to work: `from e in list select (e.Visibility == Visibility.Public && (e.Visibility == Visibility.Private && e.Author.Id == userId))`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```cs
var filteredList = list.Where(x => x.Visibility == Visibility.Public || (x.Visibility == Visibility.Private && x.AuthorId == currentUserId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking that a post has visibility public AND private at the same time. Your two conditions should use an OR not an AND.

Your condition should be `e.Visibility == Visibility.Public || (e.Visibility == Visibility.Private && e.Author.Id == userId)`

Notice the `||`